# Run Windows command After File Copy

Tags: inno-setup

I want to copy files (inputs given by user) into installed folder at the end. I believed this command would work -

```
Filename: "cmd.exe"; Parameters: "cp {code:GetClientPrivatePEM} {code:GetServerPublicPEM} ."; WorkingDir: "{app}\trust"; Flags:
```

But it does't copy and is stuck. However, I can see the output in the logs.
Is there any problem with syntax? How do I fix this?

One possible problem that can arise is if the {code:GetClientPrivatePEM} or {code:GetServerPublicPEM} has space. How do I handle that? (Current input doesn't have space)

The other way of copying that I thought of was  -

```
[Files]
 Source: "C:\Users\pnarendr\Desktop\API_DAST\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files
;Source: "C:\Users\pnarendr\Desktop\output.log"; DestDir: "{code:GetPythonHome}";
Source: "{code:GetServerPublicPEM}"; DestDir: "{app}\trust"; Flags: external ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "{code:GetClientPrivatePEM}"; DestDir: "{app}\trust"; Flags: external ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

But this says that {code:GetServerPublicPEM} is in accessible. Not Sure how

Comment: Both should work. While the approach with `[Files]` is definitely better.  And it works for me. If it does not work for you, we need [mcve].

Comment: What about this?

Comment: Figured the problem.

Comment: Answered the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the function - `GetServerPublicPEM`. In case the Page isnt assigned, send a default value.  Example

```
function GetUserID(Param: String) : string;
begin
  if Assigned(InputValuesPage) then
    Result := InputValuesPage.Values[3]
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```